# storing error message of command output into a shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to store error meesage of a copy command in to a variable. But its not happening

**Unix Command**

```
log=`cp log.txt`
cp: missing destination file operand after `log.txt'
Try `cp --help' for more information.

echo $log

<nothing displayed>
```

I want to store above error message into a variable so that i can echo it whenever i want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just redirect the stdout (normal output) to `/dev/null` and keep the stderror:

```
a=$(cp log.txt 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

See an example:

```
$ a=$(cp log.txt 2>&1 >/dev/null)
$ echo "$a"
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘log.txt’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

The importance to `>/dev/null` to keep away to normal output that in this case we do not want:

```
$ ls a b
ls: cannot access a: No such file or directory
b
$ a=$(ls a b 2>&1)
$ echo "$a"
ls: cannot access a: No such file or directory
b
$ a=$(ls a b 2>&1 >/dev/null)
$ echo "$a"
ls: cannot access a: No such file or directory
```

Note the need of quoting `$a` when calling it, so that the format is kept. Also, it is better to use `$()` rather than `, as it is easier to nest and also` is deprecated.

---

[What does `2>&1` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/1983854)

> 1 is stdout. 2 is stderr.
>
> Here is one way to remember this construct (altough it is not entirely
>   accurate): at first, `2>1` may look like a good way to redirect stderr
>   to stdout. However, it will actually be interpreted as "redirect
>   stderr to a file named `1`". `&` indicates that what follows is a file
>   descriptor and not a filename. So the construct becomes: `2>&1`.

Comment: Please explain so that i can mark as answer :)

Comment: As devnull was commenting in his deleted answer, you can check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29 Also see my updated answer.

Comment: For commands that write to both standard output and standard error, you'll want to throw away standard output after redirecting standard error:  `$( command 2>&1 >/dev/null )`.

Comment: You are completely right, @chepner, just updated showing an example of what you comment. Thanks!